# gettting 401 on Hangfire with LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter

Tags: hangfire

We are trying to use hangfire with LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter. We have deployed the application to IIS. When trying to access the hangfire dashboard from same machine where IIS is deployed, we are getting 401 on hangfire dashboard URL "/jobs". All we are trying to do here is allow to view the dashboard as long as request is coming from same machine where hangfire is deployed. Below is our config on startup.cs file

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobs, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions()
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter() }
        });
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
        });
        backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!")); 
    }
```

We checked both remote and local ip and both are same. Is there anything else we are missing here? Just to make sure application is running or not on IIS, we are added the another page and that page is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Authorization to AuthorizationFilters,

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions()
{
    AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter() }
});
```

Also, [from this post](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1339#issuecomment-465474134) check to make sure ASP.net is correctly installed and integrated pipeline is used for your application pool

[This](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Documentation/blob/master/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.rst) is also another good resource to go through in validating your IIS configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in **Docker environment**.

Using `LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter` always ended up with 401 Unauthorized.
I wrote my own `AuthorizationFilter` which had the same code as the original `LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter` so I could debug.
It turns out that the remote IP (of the browser that the request comes from) is different as the local IP (of the container).

This could probably be solved by using `network_mode: host` option while setting up a Docker container.

Here you can see the actual values of the remote and local IPs:
[image]